# Random number generation - constrained sequence

Tags: r

I'm trying to produce a set of 480 random integers between 1-9. However there are some constraints:

- the sequence cannot contain 2 duplicate digits in a row.
- the sequence must include exactly 4 sequences of odd numbers and 4 sequences of even numbers (in any order) within every 80 digit sequence (e.g. 6 4 5 **2** **4** **8** 3 4 6 **9** **1** **5** 4 6 1).

I have been able to produce a set of random numbers hat allows repeated digits, using:

```
NumRep <- sample(1:9, 480, replace=T)
```

but not been able to work out how to allow digits to be repeated over the entire set, but to not allow sequential repeats (e.g. 2 5 3 would be okay, 2 5 5 would not). I have got nowhere with the odd/even constraint.

For context, this is not homework! I am a researcher, and this is part of a psychological experiment that I am creating.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When posting a question, please share your code, and try to explain your problem as best as you can. Right now, it's very unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: Thank you for replying, and sorry for the lack of clarity - I have edited my answer.

Comment: With regard to your second point, are you saying that somewhere in the sequence of 480 numbers you must be able to find four odd numbers in a row (bounded by evens) and four even numbers in a row (bounded by odds)?

Comment: @Mist The odd/even constraint is that within every sequence of 80 digits, I need to present exactly 4 sequences of 3 odd numbers, and 4 sequences of 3 even numbers (e.g. 6 4 5 **2** **4** **8** 3 4 6 **9** **1** **5** 4 6 1). In case it helps to clarity, it is for an experiment looking at sustained attention- the numbers will be presented one at a time, and participants have to press a button when they see either 3 odd numbers or 3 even numbers in a row.

Comment: So I'm guessing you don't ever want more than three evens/odds in a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the problem loses the "random" way of simulating with that conditions. Anyway this code corresponds with the first constraint:

```
   # Build a vector 
     C<-vector()
   # Length of the vector
     n<-480
   # The first element
    C<-sample(1:9,1)
   # Complete the rest
    for (i in 2:n){
    # Take a random number not equal to the previous one
      C[i] <- sample(c(1:9)[1:9!=C[i-1]],1)
    }

    # It is an odd number?
      C %% 2 == 0
    # How many consecutive odd numbers are in the sequence?
      # Build a table with this information
        TAB <- rle( C %% 2 == 0)
        # Maximum of consecutive odd numbers
          max(TAB$lengths[TAB$values==T])
        # Maximum of consecutive even numbers
          max(TAB$lengths[TAB$values==F])
```

I don't understand the second constraint, but I hope the final part of the code helps. You should use that information in order to interchange some values.

Comment: With sequence, do you mean 3 consecutive odd (even) numbers? Because if you want to make that, may be the strategy could be to build these sequences first, and add before and after other numbers that don't follow this property.